# MVC Kendo Grid Style

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to add Style to the `.Title(title)` I want to be able to center and the change the background color?

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(pvm)
    .Name("grid" + i)
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(
        @<text>
        <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='FieldFilter' placeholder="Filter Results....">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </text>);
        })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Group(group => group
        .Title(title)
        .Columns(info =>
        {
        info.Bound(x => x.PanelName).Width(200);
        info.Bound(x => x.MeetingDate).Width(200);
        info.Bound(x => x.Type).Width(200);
        })
    );
})
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the header with css. See this example below;

```
#MyGridID .k-grid-header .k-header 
{
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Where #MyGridID is the name of your grid.